# uninitialized constant PublicActivity::ORM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, public-activity

I already have an table with name activities so I created public_activity.rb file with this line as some one suggested in an issue

```
PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity.table_name = "notifications"
```

but when I try to run

```
rails g public_activity:migration notifications
```

it fails because of a name error uninitialized constant PublicActivity::ORM (NameError). Any one can resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to set a custom table name. Just put this in your initializer:

```
# config/initializers/public_activity.rb
PublicActivity.configure do |config|
  config.table_name = 'notifications'
end
```